# Redirecting Django root to admin panel

Tags: python, django, apache, django-admin, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to redirect the Django site root to the Django admin panel, and I've mostly got it up and running.  However, I've noticed that unless there's a trailing slash in the project URL, the links on the page don't include the project folder, and instead try to find the apps in the site root.

So, say I've got a project `foo`, and an app `bar`. If you visit `http://server/foo/` (with a trailing slash), everything works fine, and the links on the page go to `http://server/foo/bar`. However, if one visits `http://server/foo`, the generated links go to `http://server/bar` instead, which generates a 404 error.

If I set the `WSGIScriptAlias` to point to `/foo/` instead of `/foo`, it would give a 404 error if I navigated to `/foo`. I tried to force a trailing slash in the Apache conf with Redirect, but I end up generating a recursive redirect (`http://server/foo//////...`). I haven't yet tried using a .htaccess file, but I suspect the same thing might happen.

I tried the same thing in `urls.py`, however:

```
url(r'^$', redirect_to, {'url': '/'}), # goes to server root http://server/
url(r'^$', redirect_to, {'url': 'foo/'}), # goes to http://server/foo/foo
url(r'^$', redirect_to, {'url': '/foo/'}), # infinite redirect
```

I also tried simply appending a slash to all the Django urls like so:

```
url(r'^(.*)/', include(admin.site.urls))
```

But it fails to match anything at all in the project root folder (although if you navigate to the app, that seems to work OK).

I'm using Apache 2.2 with mod_wsgi, here is the configuration:

```
Alias /static "C:/DJANGO~1/apps/django/django/contrib"

<Directory 'C:/DJANGO~1/apps/django/django/contrib'>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /foo "C:/Djangostack/apps/django/scripts/django.wsgi"

<Directory 'C:/Djangostack/apps/django/scripts'>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And this is the `urls.py` that mostly works:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I've made sure `APPEND_SLASH` is set to True, but it doesn't seem to work in the root project folder.

Comment: Why would `/foo` get redirected to `/bar`? Where is this redirect happening?

Comment: It's not really `/foo` getting redirected to `/bar` - instead, the urls generated on the page go to `/bar` instead of `/foo/bar`.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#append-slash) to True in your `settings.py`. I had a similar problem and this fixed it for me. It's supposed to default to True but I had to set it explicitly.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help - it works everywhere _but_ the project root.

Comment: Which `urls.py` does this not work with? Note it will only append a slash if the url does not match a pattern *without* the slash.

Comment: I tried it with `r'^'`, `r'^(.*)/'`, and `r'^(.*)/$'`, still no luck. I suspect that means the configuration needs to happen in Apache, or in some other system-wide Django setting.

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused why you're getting an infinite redirect with `url(r'^$', redirect_to, '/foo/')`. I do this to redirect from root to `/blog/` and it works fine. Could you post your full `urls.py` in the OP?

Comment: The infinite redirect seems to happen because it's not going from a root folder to a subfolder, but simply appending a slash to the root folder - even with that slash appended, it'll still match `r'^$'`.

I'd also realised I'd used the wrong syntax in the OP - `redirect_to` needs a dictionary, not a string. I had been using it correctly in my `urls.py`, though.